# Can I modify web pages in Chrome using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, browser, automation

I know I can use JavaScript to modify a webpage. But I want to know if it's possible to use Delphi to do the same thing. For example, can I add a DOM element into the webpage I'm currently viewing? I want to do some browser automation using Delphi.

Comment: Ar you embedding an instance of Chrome inside of your Delphi app? Or, are you wanting to modify content inside an external Chrome instance?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to modify the content inside an external Chrome instance.

Comment: you can use WebBrowser ```WebBrowser.OleObject.document.body.innerHTML``` by windows' WebBrowser